ObservedObject vs. StateObject behaviour
struct WeakSelfBootcamp: View {
    
    @AppStorage("count") var count: Int?
    
    init() {
        count = 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Navigate", destination: WeakSelfSecondScreen())
                .navigationTitle("Screen 1")
        }
        .overlay(
            Text("\(count ?? 0)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green.cornerRadius(10))
            , alignment: .topTrailing
        )
    }
}

struct WeakSelfSecondScreen: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = WeakSelfSecondScreenViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text(String(vm.data))
                
            
            
        }
        .onAppear{
                vm.changeData()
            }
    }
}


class WeakSelfSecondScreenViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var data: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        print("INITIALIZE NOW")
        let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount + 1, forKey: "count")
        getData()
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("DEINITIALIZE NOW")
        let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount - 1, forKey: "count")
    }
    
    func changeData(){
        data = data + 2
    }
    
    func getData() {
        
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 500) { [weak self] in
//            self?.data = "NEW DATA!!!!"
//        }
        self.data = 0
        
    }
    
}


why this is not working? it shows me nothing on screen (preview) and when I am changing observedObject to stateObject, it is working but view model gets re-initiated whenever I click navigationLink, which should not be the case.
can you explain how stateObject works with navigationLink?

Why should "view model gets re initiated whenever I click navigation link" not be the case? It's the view model for the second screen isn't it?

In the first version of SwiftUI @ObservedObject could be used for owning the object or being handed over. Nowadays use always @StateObject if you create the object like in your example and @ObservedObject (not initialized)  if the object is passed through. By the way declaring integers in AppStorage as optional is pointless. UserDefaults returns non-optional 0 if the key is missing. And then the init method is redundant, too.

StateObject has lifecycle management, ObservedObject does not so it will get recreated randomly. Also, AppStorage can be used inside an ObservableObject

ObservedObject was never meant to be an owner, a lot of us used it as an owner (including me in 2019). The owner was always meant to be something else like a FetchRequest or a State or something else. In iOS 14 Apple added StateObject which has likecycle like State + ObservableObject.

when I am using observedObject, the preview is showing blank white page and I think it is due to navigationLink not rendered properly ,and when I am using stateObject ,console is printing "initialize now" and deinitialize now" whenever I switch between views , but we know that stateObject persist even when view is redrawn , then why this is happening. I am writing this code only to see the behaviour of stateObject and observedObject

Redrawn is different than recreated. You likely have a memory leak.

"stateObject persist even when view is redrawn" is true. But stateObject does not persist when view is deinitiazed and recreated i.e. reinitialized. StateObject must be also recreated when the view is reinitiazed, otherwise it would have some memory leak.

@MahiAlJawad SwiftUI Views get “reinitialized” all the time. StateObject gets recreated/reset when the View’s Identity changes.

Use View structs for your view model data. Observed objects are for your models


You have to use @StateObject in your case as your view (WeakSelfSecondScreen) owns WeakSelfSecondScreenViewModel object. You could use @ObservedObject only when this object would be injected (i.e. passed as an argument) from some other view and the other view owns the object.
The behavior you see in case of @StateObject that the vm is reinitialized is also expected. Each time you tap on "navigate" it should be reinitialized as the view is newly being opened. Perhaps you learned somewhere that @StateObject retains the state, that is when the view is redrawn, not in case of reinitialization. Reading the whole thread I guess you mixed up the concept of a view being reinitialized and a view being redrawn.

It could be a good article for you to understand the differences: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/stateobject-observedobject-differences/
